# Is it UB to reference bind to underlying type of enum class object?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Is it UB to reference bind to underlying type of `enum class` object?

I'm aware of the danger of pass-through return reference of the `as_int` function.  The thunking function is just to help explain the question.

XY problem - after a bunch of inline operators to `static_cast` to/from underlying type at appropriate places, I found this to be an easier to use alternative in places.  But I am unsure if it is **undefined behavior**, and the `reinterpret_cast` takes off the safety.  The public facing API of the `enum class` would not expose this pattern; it is just for private use in the implementation file.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

enum class Int : int {};
inline auto as_int(Int& i) -> int& {
    return reinterpret_cast<int&>(i);
}

int main() {
    Int i{100};
    int& r = as_int(i);
    cout << r << "\n"; //> 100
    as_int(i) = 107;
    cout << r << "\n"; //> 107
}
```

Comment: Given the fact that this is a native type, and it's going to end up somewhere, if the driver for trying to do this is some kind of a micro-optimization, it is likely that all this hoop-jumping will get compiled down to the same exact code as a plain `static_cast`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik • on my compilers, yes, both the more verbose `static_cast` way and this (after user17732522's answer) UB way it does compile to the same thing.  Both in debug builds and optimized release builds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing the return value of `as_int(i)` as done in your `main` is an aliasing violation and therefore causes undefined behavior. The relevant paragraph of the standard ([[basic.lval]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr#basic.lval-11)) does not list underlying types of enumeration types as specifically allowed to alias.

Currently the standard doesn't even specify that the enumeration type and the underlying type will share the same alignment. If it was different then the cast would not even preserve the value (so that a round-trip cast would be unsafe). But that seems like a defect, see [CWG 2590](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2590.html).

Alignment issues aside, the cast itself does not have undefined behavior, but accessing the enumeration object through the resulting reference does.

Comment: Thank you!  You've talked me down off the ledge.